# How to have a watermark text in Datepicker in wp7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, datepicker

**Scenario:**

As the title implies, I need a watermark text to be pasted on the datepicker control but the 'value' property does not accept any thing other than date format.  I have tried adding the textblock in the backkground to achieve this. but the problem is that, the datepicker page is not popping up when tapping the text block. Can this be done. If not, what is the other way around to prompt a user to select the date say 'Date of birth'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be this post will help you to implement such control for Windows Phone <http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2010/05/06/changing-the-watermark-text-in-a-datepicker-control.aspx>. And from the other side in case DatePicker is not extensible, you can implement your own control with such possibility, use a simple TextBox, after it is tapped, user will be navigated to a page with LoopingSelector where a date can be chosen.

Comment: Did you try disabling hit testing on `TextBlock`?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your replies. I have succeeded it but rather in a tricky way..
what i have done is:

**In Xaml:**

I have kept my datepicker 'foreground' value to none/transparent. Hence the background textblock text will be visible which serves a watermark text.

**In cs:**

In the datepicker tap event, I have set the datepicker foreground value to black and set the visibility of the textblock to collapsed.

This is one workaround it flashed in my mind. Please let me know if something smoother than this will do that. Thanks.